# Python3 - Reading mixed data from a file and convert the read values to float

Tags: python-3.x, string, numpy

I have the following data stored in a file (tn.csv). 
The content is as follows (Original file is very large but I simplified it):
[file_content.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OluWr.png)

I read the data using the following source code:
[python_script.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsJ23.png)

It nicely produces the following which is a *numpy array of strings*. 
[sample_output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkfsW.png)

Ultimately I want to use the read data as a *numpy array of floats* in my python script. 
All the entries should be float values. Hence, I would like to cast the entries from *string* to *float*. As some entries are not numbers but strings of text (they are variables in my script), I could not perform type casting directly. Python throws a ValueError.

Note: I define the (vector) variable **nv** before I read this matrix. Hence, it is well defined. *So, the complexity is that some entries of the numpy arrays are variables*.

What I would like to have is the following: 
If I had directly typed the file (tn.csv) contents in the form of numpy array in my python script, I would have been able to use it directly without any conversion. But the matrix is very big. So, I store it in an external file. Now, I want to read the file and store it in a numpy array. The end result should be the same as if I had typed it directly in my script. Could someone help me to tackle this issue or provide me relevant links?

This is my first post in stack**overflow**. If my question is not clear, please let me know. 
I will rewrite it.

Comment: Normally `csv` files have uniform columns - labels, numbers etc. You have mixed values, some rows numbers, others look like python code.  I think you should write a function that handles one string (row element) (this isn't a simple `type` conversion), apply to strings in a line, and so on.  You won't find `numpy` code that does that for you, especially since the strings are supposed to use local variables.

Comment: Your suggestion clarified some of doubts. I found it very helpful. (Is this the way to show gratitude or should I do something else;) ?) Thank you, @hpaulj